# What is best method to detect user typing at server side code. In web based chat app?

Tags: php, jquery, chat

I'am now developing web based chat like (example: startdevelop livehelp, zopim, etc) .  I want to add `module/feature` that show both of `admin` and `visitor` `"typing.. / is writing a message.."`  information.

I have insert jquery change/keyup function. But then? what should i do. Insert value that user "is typing" to database? and client browser always check in interval.

I think, that way can make server busy.

Is there better solution?

Thank you

Comment: `.focus()` and `.blur()`?

Comment: Update the database with a "last time the user was typing" field. If you use websockets it's as simple as sending out a "user is typing" packet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a form with some elements:

```
<input type='text' id='textField' />
<textarea id='textarea'></textarea>
```

You can detect typing with:

```
$('#textField').change(function() {
    //report to the server
});
```

or

```
$('#textarea').keyup(function() {
    //report to the server
});
```

How your application handles and displays the 'typing' status is entirely dependent upon your application and database.  My suggestion would be to use the typing events to trigger a database insert like this:

```
UPDATE tbl_chatrooms SET typingmoment = NOW() WHERE chatID = :chatID AND userID = :userID;
```

Then, your AJAX running at an interval would make a request to the server which would return data from a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT userID, IF(typingmoment > NOW() - INTERVAL 10 SECOND, 1, 0) AS typing FROM tbl_chatrooms WHERE chatID = :chatID;
```

Basically, this will return a 1 or a 0 for each user in the chat based upon whether they have typed anything in the last 10 seconds.  You'd probably run your interval at 5 seconds or so.

Edit:  This handles the basics, but as it sits, someone typing a 100 character message would end up sending 100 ajax requests to the server.  Best to set a flag, then report to the server at an interval.

Something else to consider is to make sure your interval calls kill any active previous calls.  Set the ajax call to a `window.` global variable, then you can abort it at the next interval, in case it's still running.  That way, if there is a hiccup in your internet connection, or your internet connection is slow, you don't have a whole bunch of ajax requests piling up on a schedule.  Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery) to see how to cancel requests.

Comment: Thank you @SuperJet . That code is on front end side. I have no idea in server side code. What should i write in ajax code. Send value "typing" to database. And client browser always check (in interval) ?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a little SQL to help you get started.

Answer (score 3):

You can catch keypress event on the textarea, and use setTimeout to detect when the user has stopped typing for a while.
Using AJAX you can send those events to the server for processing.
Check out these links:
http://api.jquery.com/keypress/
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout

Comment: Also check out the docs for jQuery's ajax function: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/